# JQ - Join nested arrays and filter

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to use JQ to create the following paths:

```
/staging-data-0/cassandra/cassandra-client-port
/staging-data-0/cassandra/cassandra-gossip-port
```

from the following blob of JSON (I've stripped unnecessary bits out):

```
{
  "DebugConfig": {
    "ServerPort": 8300,
    "Services": [
      {
        "Checks": [
          {
            "CheckID": "cassandra-client-port",
            "Timeout": "1s"
          },
          {
            "CheckID": "cassandra-gossip-port",
            "Timeout": "1s"
          }
        ],
        "Name": "cassandra"
      },
      {
        "Checks": [
          {
            "CheckID": "cockroachdb-tcp",
            "Timeout": "1s"
          }
        ],
        "Name": "cockroachdb"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Member": {
    "Name": "staging-data-0"
  },
  "Meta": {
      "consul-network-segment": ""
  }
}
```

I'm struggling with the JQ manual to generate the paths, I can only pull out the last part so far with

```
jq '.DebugConfig.Services | map(select(.Name=="cassandra")) | map(.Checks[].CheckID)'
```

The final path should be `/{.Member.Name}/{.DebugConfig.Services.Name}/{.DebugConfig.Services.Checks.CheckID}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `cassandra`

```
jq -r '{a:.Member.Name, b:.DebugConfig.Services[]} | select(.b.Name=="cassandra") | {a:.a, b:.b.Name, c:.b.Checks[].CheckID} | [.a, .b, .c] | join("/")'
staging-data-0/cassandra/cassandra-client-port
staging-data-0/cassandra/cassandra-gossip-port
```

Both

```
jq -r '{a:.Member.Name, b:.DebugConfig.Services[]} | {a:.a, b:.b.Name, c:.b.Checks[].CheckID} | [.a, .b, .c] | join("/")'
staging-data-0/cassandra/cassandra-client-port
staging-data-0/cassandra/cassandra-gossip-port
staging-data-0/cockroachdb/cockroachdb-tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

With your input, the jq filter:

```
.DebugConfig.Services[] as $s
| "/\(.Member.Name)/\($s.Name)/\($s.Checks[].CheckID)"
```

produces:

```
"/staging-data-0/cassandra/cassandra-client-port"
"/staging-data-0/cassandra/cassandra-gossip-port"
"/staging-data-0/cockroachdb/cockroachdb-tcp"
```

Since you only want the "cassandra" strings, you just need to interject a "select" filter:

```
.DebugConfig.Services[] as $s
| "/\(.Member.Name)/\($s.Name)/" +
    ($s
     | select(.Name == "cassandra")
     | .Checks[].CheckID)
```

but it's worth noting how easy it is to process all the "Checks" items.